# jQuery template select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, select, jquery-templates

How do I use jQuery templates to select an option?

Let's say my data is: `{ "color" : "red" }`

I have :

```
<select>
  <option>blue</option>
  <option>green</option>
  <option>red</option>
</select>
```

I want red to be the one that's selected by default. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant, but here is a way to do it in your template: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/z7Uu7/

```
<select>
    <option {{if color == 'blue'}}selected{{/if}}>blue</option>
    <option {{if color == 'green'}}selected{{/if}}>green</option>
    <option {{if color == 'red'}}selected{{/if}}>red</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("select").val(data['color']);
```

Comment: Oops, just noticed the template keyword. But this should work after the template is inserted in to the DOM anyways.

Comment: Thanks but for the question is meant for templates.

Comment: But actually I don't see the reason here to use templates. Aren't templates for dynamically replacing string occurances? Another way, that has nothing to do with templates, really:   $.tmpl( myTemplate, data).appendTo( "#moviesList" ).find("select").val(data['color']);

Comment: The point of the template is to put it in the html rather than the code. I think it should be possible...

Comment: $.tmpl( myTemplate, data).appendTo( "#moviesList" ).find("select").val(data['color']); --> it has worked very well, congratulations!